# Why is @Value Attribute null?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jdbc, null

I'm currently trying to wire a database from my application.properties file to get a JDBC connection in a different class. I used the following method to do so.

```
@Component
public class databaseConn {
    public static int counter=0;
    @Value("${spring.datasource.url}")
    private String url;
    @Value("${spring.datasource.username}")
    private String username;
    @Value("${spring.datasource.password}")
    private String password;

    //Retrieves Everything from the database and sends it to the front end
    public ArrayList<Alert> datacon() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
        ArrayList<Alert> giveBack = new ArrayList<Alert>();
        Statement stmt = null;
        Connection conn=null;
        System.out.println(url);
        System.out.println(username);
        System.out.println(password);
        try {
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println("Couldn't Connect");
        }
```

For some reason when I print the values, they are showing up as Null and cant connect. What am I doing wrong?

Edit: Here is the application.properties file. I redacted the values for each field but everything else can be seen

```
spring.application.name=sampleApp
spring.datasource.url=xxxx
spring.datasource.username=username
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.http.encoding.enabled=false
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect
```

Comment: Can you show the application.properties file?

Comment: @ErkanErkişi Just added it

Comment: There's a lot of reasons those can be null.  Also, keep in mind that if you are using spring.datasource, you can just Autowire the datasource directly.

Comment: Yea i agree with @lane.maxwell. I think your class not scanned as a component in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

When are you calling datacon()?  If you're doing it from the constructor those values will not yet be set (the properties are injected after the class is constructed, unless you add them to the constructor using constructor injection).  If you want to verify they're being set, which from looking at the code and your properties they should be, add a PostContruct method.

```
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;

...

@PostConstruct
public void verifyMyPrope() {
  System.out.println(username);
}
```

As a side note, unless this is test code, avoid using the System.out, that's naughty :)